# Find the number of users for which there is no subsequent status

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the below Payment table. The Process followed is first the payment is batched and then approved.

```
CREATE TABLE payments (userid int, status varchar(255), city_id int, payment_processing datetime)

insert into payments(userid,status,city_id,payment_processing) values
(1,                     'approved'     ,01,        '2019-07-07 19:24:28:15'),
(1,                     'batched',      01,        '2019-07-07 19:24:28:10'),
(2,                     'approved' ,    02,        '2019-07-07 20:24:28:22'),
(2 ,                    'batched'  ,    02    ,    '2019-07-07 20:24:28:09'),
(3,                     'batched'   ,   03     ,   '2019-07-07 20:24:28:09')
```

I would like to find the number of users for which there is no subsequent status after 'batched'.

That means, if an user_id has "**batched**" status , the next row for that user_id should not have any subsequent status.

How can I achieve this using SQL query.

Comment: can you post your expected output for above input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find the number of users for which status is 'batched' but not 'approved'
Try the below query

```
select count(*) as no_of_users_with_only_batched
from(
SELECT DISTINCT USERID
FROM PAYMENTS
WHERE STATUS='batched'
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT USERID
FROM PAYMENTS
WHERE STATUS='approved') p
```

Comment: The `SELECT DISTINCT` is redundant, because `EXCEPT` removed duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You can list those users using nested query:

```
SELECT * FROM payments where payment_processing =
(SELECT MAX(payment_processing) FROM payments  t1 WHERE t1.userid = payments.userid )
AND status = 'batched'
```

Clearly, to get number instead of list you just need to adjust it a little

Answer (score 0):

you can use row_number to achieve the results.

```
select t1.userid, t1.city_id, t1.payment_processing, case t1.rn when 1 then t1.status else '' end from
payments t2
left join (
select *, row_number() over (partition by userid order by payment_processing asc) as rn from payments) t1 on t1.userid = t2.userid
    and t1.status=t2.status and t1.payment_processing=t2.payment_processing
order by t2.payment_processing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from 
(select userid from payments where status='batched')a
left join 
(select userid from payments where status<>'batched')b
on a.userid = b.userid 
where b.userid is null
```